# input data from vba userform textbox to a spreadsheet cell depending on the time and date

Tags: vba, textbox, range

This has boggled my mind for the last few weeks, research hasn't turned up an answer for me as yet.

I have a User form with a set of textboxes to input data to every hour (form has a combobox with the hours on it which the user selects). This data then should be sent to a sheet into respective cells under column headings (z1, z2 and so on) and into the corresponding rows according to the time and date. User form has a label which displays current date, I have tried to get the code to read the current date, then select the time in the combobox and place data into the cells.

I am currently getting an Object Required Error. on the date label. have I defined this wrong?

When I change the code and remove "As Date" the code fills all the cells with the actual text "TextBox193"etc in the entire column respective to the range that was specified, am I missing a command/piece of code here to set the destination more specifically?

```
Private Sub Commandbutton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim formDate
Dim formTime As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

'Destination sheet
Set ws = Sheet59
 'Label on userform displaying current date
    Set formDate = UserForm1.Label35
'Label on userform diplaying a set time on the half hour (if within a 
certain range)
    Set formTime = UserForm1.ComboBox1
'Range Columns
Range("E2").Value = TextBox193.Text
Range("G2").Value = TextBox194.Text
Range("I2").Value = TextBox195.Text
Range("K2").Value = TextBox196.Text
Range("M2").Value = TextBox197.Text
Range("O2").Value = TextBox198.Text
Range("Q2").Value = TextBox199.Text
Range("S2").Value = TextBox200.Text
Range("U2").Value = TextBox201.Text

Dim x As Integer
For x = 193 To 201
Me.Controls("textbox" & x).Value = ""
Next x
Cancel = MsgBox("Data Input Successful")

Me.Hide

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: `z1.Value = "TextBox193.Text"` will set the value to the string `"TextBox193.Text"`. If you want to set it to the value, remove the quotes, i.e. `z1.Value = TextBox193.Text`

Comment: `Set formDate = Label35` probably fails because `formDate` is of type date and `Label35`, a label, is a string.

Comment: Hey, Thanks  Paul. I now have numbers! Superb. Have i messed up in the "Set" Range by typing ("E:E") etc, is there something I should have put which limits to where the data is placed when submitted? I started this process thinking it would be something along the lines of a Vlookup type procedure with the opposite effect (a VInsert if you will)

I have removed "As Date" and that made it input the data in whole columns, With "As String" I get Compile Error, Object Required.

Comment: Hi, I have restructured the code as I discovered i didn't need to declare variables for textboxes. I have edited the code above.

But, I know i need to get rid of "E2" for something else. I don't think IF,Then,Else will work as i need more than a True/False on the IF.

Which function should I look at to read the "formDate" label then the "formTime" combobox to tell the data where to go? Thanks